# SelectPDF ASP.NET MVC how to pass page number into header table template if my header is converted using html string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-to-pdf, selectpdf

I am using following code to create header in selectPDF.

```
string headerUrl = ViewToHtmlAsync("~/Views/HeaderTemplate/Header.cshtml");

PdfHtmlSection headerHtml = new PdfHtmlSection(headerUrl,"https://selectpdf.com/demo/files/header.html");
converter.Header.Add(headerHtml);
```

ViewToHtmlAsync is the function that convert .cshtml file to html string. The Header.cshtml will generate following template.

[image]

But currently the page number data "1 of 2" is hardcoded.

My question is how do I pass the page number from the controller to Header.cshtml and put it inside the table so that I got the correct page number data on each page? It seems like only the placeholder {page_number} and {total_pages} can generate the page number? If yes, how do I pass it into my Header.cshtml? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I work for SelectPdf.*

Placeholders for page numbers cannot be used inside HTML. If you need the page number in the header of the pdf, you would need to use a PdfTextSection object:

```
// page numbers can be added using a PdfTextSection object
PdfTextSection text = new PdfTextSection(0, 10, "Page: {page_number} of {total_pages}  ", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8));
text.HorizontalAlign = PdfTextHorizontalAlign.Right;
converter.Header.Add(text);
```

Comment: How to use customer header on specific page? I read through your documentation, [link]https://selectpdf.com/docs/HtmlToPdfHeadersAndFooters.htm, but I'm stuck at customHeader.Add(), because I can't use PdfHtmlElement, I can only use PdfHtmlSection

Comment: I am afraid that is only available for the paid version of the library. You cannot use page numbers with the free community edition.